# Why aren't users able to post on Facebook while I can as administrator?

Tags: social-network

I am getting the following message while submitting a post.

> Refresh your session by visiting "admin/config/services/publish-away"
>   and disconnect the Facebook app and reconnect it. OAuthException An
>   active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user.

I have set all the setting correctly, and I can post from admin account but my users can't although I give them the right permission. What's wrong?

Comment: Well I tried this module too and faced same issue. Then I dropped the idea of using it. Try Facebook Autopost module which works great.